# How to Show External website inside angular page without web elements

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, navigation

I have a global navigation. On each nav link click its corresponding app will open and that app can be on any technology. So basically our nav should have that feature to integrate any app on it container.
Global nav is in angular. I know we can do this with angular web elements if that app is in angular but what if thats not in angular or have older versions of angular which don't support web elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try iFrame for it.

```js
<iframe id="theFrame" src="http://www.github.com" style="width:100%;" frameborder="3">
</iframe>
```

Comment: I don't want to use iframe, because my nav should be global/same for all the opening apps